# If $α, β, γ$ are roots of $x^3 - x -1 = 0$, then find the value of $\frac{1+α}{1-α} + \frac{1+β}{1-β} + \frac{1+γ}{1-γ}$.

Tags: polynomials, roots, cubics, symmetric-polynomials

If $α, β, γ$ are roots of $x^3 - x -1 = 0$, then find the value of  $$\frac{1+α}{1-α} + \frac{1+β}{1-β} + \frac{1+γ}{1-γ}$$
I found this question asked in a previous year competitive examination, which was multiple choice in nature, the available options to the question were:

1. $1$
2. $0$
3. $-7$
4. $-5$

Considering the time available for a question to be solved in such an examination, is there a way to solve this problem without actually having to expand the the given relation by cross-multiplying the numerators and denominators or even finding the zeroes of the given equation.

Comment: This works the same way as [here](https://www.quora.com/If-a-b-c-are-the-roots-of-x-3-x-2-1-0-Then-what-will-be-the-value-of-Σ-1+a-1-a).

Comment: @DietrichBurde The correct  answer was given as -7 and not -5. It could verified when done the long way. There's a mistake in the given solution.

Comment: The given solution refers to $x^3-x^2-1$, and not $x^3-x-1$. But the method to solve is the same. Just do it!

Comment: Self-contained hint: if $\alpha$ is a root of $x^3-x-1$, find a (cubic) polynomial that $(1+\alpha)/(1-\alpha)$ is a root of. (This is pretty straightforward; if $\alpha'=(1+\alpha)/(1-\alpha)$ then just invert to find $\alpha$ in terms of $\alpha'$, plug that in to the defining polynomial, and collect some terms - it's a little bit of an algebraic slog, but not too bad since it's only a single variable.) Then $\alpha'$, $\beta'$, and $\gamma'$ are roots of this polynomial, and if you have the three roots of a polynomial you should know how to find their sum...

Comment: @DietrichBurde Sorry I didn't immediately notice. But thanks. Could this be done in a yet more simpler way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is practical to recall that $z\mapsto\frac{1-z}{1+z}$ is an [involution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics)). In particular
$$ \frac{1+\alpha}{1-\alpha}+\frac{1+\beta}{1-\beta}+\frac{1+\gamma}{1-\gamma} $$
is the sum of the reciprocal of the roots of $p\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)=-\frac{x^3-x^2+7x+1}{(1+x)^3}$, which is also the sum of the reciprocal of the roots of $x^3-x^2+7x+1$. By [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), this is $\color{red}{-7}$ (option 3.).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** If $\zeta$ is a root of $p(x)$, then $\zeta' := 1 - \zeta$ is a root of $-p(1 - x)$. Taking $p(x) := x^3 - x - 1$ gives $$q(x) := -p(1 - x) = x^3 - 3 x^2 + 2 x + 1 .$$

Now, $$\frac{1 + \zeta}{1 - \zeta} = \frac{1 + (1 - \zeta')}{\zeta'} = \frac{2}{\zeta'} - 1,$$ so
$$S := \frac{1 + \alpha}{1 - \alpha} + \frac{1 + \beta}{1 - \beta} + \frac{1 + \gamma}{1 - \gamma} = 2 \left(\frac{1}{\alpha'} + \frac{1}{\beta'} + \frac{1}{\gamma'}\right) - 3,$$
where we define $\alpha'$ etc. analogously to $\zeta'$ above, so that $\alpha', \beta', \gamma'$ are the roots of $q$.

Now, similarly transform $q(x)$ to find a polynomial $r(x)$ whose roots are $\alpha'' := \frac{1}{\alpha'}$, etc., and observe that
$$r(x) = (x - \alpha'')(x - \beta'')(x - \gamma') = x^3 - (\alpha'' + \beta'' + \gamma'')x^2 + \cdots$$ and that the sum is the above expression for the desired quantity $S$ is exactly the negative $\alpha'' + \beta'' + \gamma''$ of the coefficient of the quadratic term.

> **Additional hint** If $\alpha'' := \frac{1}{\alpha'}, \beta'' := \frac{1}{\beta'}, \gamma'' := \frac{1}{\gamma'}$ are the roots of $$r(x) := x^3 q\left(\tfrac{1}{x}\right) = x^3 + 2 x^2 - 3 x + 1,$$ then $\alpha'' + \beta'' + \gamma'' = -2$, and so $$S = 2 (\alpha'' + \beta'' + \gamma'') - 3 = 2(-2) - 3 = -7.$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $x^3-x-1=0$ is equivalent to $x^3-x=1$ and $x^3-1=x$.  That is, for $x\in\{\alpha,\beta,\gamma\}$, we get
$$-x-x^2=\frac{x^3-x}{1-x}=\frac{1}{1-x}\text{ and }-1-x-x^2=\frac{x^3-1}{1-x}=\frac{x}{1-x}\,.$$
Consequently, $$\frac{1+x}{1-x}=-1-2x-2x^2\text{ for }x\in\{\alpha,\beta,\gamma\}\,.$$
This means
$$\sum_{x\in\{\alpha,\beta,\gamma\}}\,\frac{1+x}{1-x}=-3-2s-2q\,,$$
where $s:=\alpha+\beta+\gamma$ and $q:=\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2$.  It is easy to find $s$ and $q$.

> We have $s=0$ and $q=2$.

Comment: Could you elaborate the answer a little bit. I couldn't catch up certain steps you did.

Comment: @Tony1970  You have to point out what you don't understand.  I don't know where to start.

Comment: How does $ - x - x^2 = \frac{x^3 - x}{1-x} = \frac{1}{1-x}$ and why is **"and - 1"** used. And I did not understand the equivalence of $x^3-x-1=0$ to $x^3-x=1$ and $x^3-1=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Alt. hint:   Let $y = \dfrac{1+x}{1-x} \iff x = \dfrac{y-1}{y+1}$ then:

$$
\begin{align}
0 = (y+1)^3 \cdot P\left(\dfrac{y-1}{y+1}\right)
 &= (y-1)^3-(y-1)(y+1)^3-(y+1)^3 \\
 &= -y^3 - 7 y^2 + y - 1
\end{align}
$$

It follows from Vieta's relations that $\;y_1+y_2+y_3=\ldots$

Answer (score 1):

Since $$\alpha+\beta+\gamma=0,$$ $$\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma+\beta\gamma=-1$$ and $$\alpha\beta\gamma=1,$$ we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1+\alpha}{1-\alpha}=\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}(1+\alpha)(1-\beta)(1-\gamma)}{\prod\limits_{cyc}(1-\alpha)}=\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}(1+\alpha)(1-\beta-\gamma+\beta\gamma)}{1-(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)+(\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma+\beta\gamma)-\alpha\beta\gamma}=$$
$$=\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}(1-2\alpha+\alpha\beta+\alpha-2\alpha\beta+\alpha\beta\gamma)}{1-0-1-1}=\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}(1-\alpha-\alpha\beta+\alpha\beta\gamma)}{-1}=\frac{3+1+3}{-1}=-7.$$